# iOS initWithCoder/decodeObjectForKey memory leak

Tags: iphone

The Leaks instrument tells me that I have a memory leak when I use `decodeObjectForKey` within `initWithCoder`.    For example:

```
Class.h
{
MyObject *myObject;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *myObject;

Class.m

@synthesize myObject

-(void)dealloc{
 [myObject release];
 [super release];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
 if (self = [super init]{
 self.myObject = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MyObject"];
 }
 return self;
}
```

Per request in the comments:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{

    [encoder encodeObject:myObject forKey:@"MyObject"];

}
```

Leaks reports a leak of type NSCFString on the line;

```
 self.myObject = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"MyObject];
```

As I understand it, decodeObjectForKey returns an autoreleased object.  Since I immediately assign that value to the myObject property, which is specified as (nontoxic, retain) in the property definition, I retain the autoreleased object through the setter method of the myObject property.  The myObject is then released in the dealloc method.  I don't understand where the leak is if I understand the sequence correctly.  Also why is it reported as a NSCFString when the type is MYObject?

Any thoughts would be appreciated, including if my assumptions above are correct.

Comment: next time, please format your code:)

Comment: Then I want to see your encodeObject:forKey: method implement

Comment: New to site, sorry about the format.  Added the encodeObject: method per request

Answer (score 5):

Look carefully at your `-dealloc` method. You are calling `[super release];` when you should be calling `[super dealloc];`.

Calling `[super release]` in this case is the same thing as calling `[self release]`, since you're not overriding the `-release` method. If your `-dealloc` method is called, your object has already been fully released, so this is unnecessary. Since you are overriding the `-dealloc` method, you must call `[super dealloc]` to also free any memory allocated by the superclass.

You can [refer to the NSObject documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc) to see how to override dealloc correctly.

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation.